# Bash Script for loop that is breaking lines up instead of using the whole line

Tags: bash

I am writing a very simple script and I'm getting stuck on something stupid.  Basically I have text file in which each line is comprised of 3 words separated by a space.  When you cat the file it shows everything correctly.  For example catting the file looks something like this:

```
bird dog mouse
ferret bunny hare
```

I'm doing a simple for loop like this:

```
for line in $(cat pets.txt)
do
     echo $line
     "command $line"
done
```

The echo is showing the problem.  The command needs to run as

```
command bird dog mouse
```

and instead it is running as

```
command bird
command dog
command mouse
```

This seems like it should be a simple fix, but I can't get my search terms right to find the solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that using `cat` in a subshell substitution like this will make bash tokenize the output according to `IFS`, which by default includes spaces. This is the normal behavior for a `for` loop. Probably the easiest fix is:

```
while read line
do
     echo $line
     command $line
done < pets.txt
```

Note that `bash` will split the args up to `command`, howver. If you wanted the line as one arg, then just quote it:

```
while read line
do
     echo $line
     command "$line"
done < pets.txt
```

Comment: It's not `cat` in a subshell *per se*, but the semantics of `for`.

Comment: Right, bad wording on my part. What you say is correct.